# How to remove parent link from link for category in Joomla 3.6.2

Tags: url, joomla, menu

Recently, i have upgrade Joomla and components. After that, some things have changed on category page. It was article order and number of articles per page. I have change these in options for these menu item. I have only change article order to most recent first and articles to list to 20. I did not change anything else, but the link to that page has changed. Before was site.com/categoryname and now is site.com/com-jm-video-galleries-title-videos/categoryname. How can i remove com-jm-video-galleries-title-videos from link and get back the old link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was also posted in the Joomla forum. Try rebuilding your menu items, by clicking on the "Rebuild" button in the affected menu, and see if that fixes the problem. If it doesn't, then also try rebuilding categories. Make sure you clear your Joomla cache before testing the website.

This issue is likely caused by some problems in your assets table - so it's a good idea to install a Joomla extension to fix the assets table.